# iOS - How to send file from one app to other specific app

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, url-scheme, uidocumentinteraction

I want to send `.pdf` or image file from my app1 to app2 like [instagram hooks](https://www.instagram.com/developer/mobile-sharing/iphone-hooks/). I don't want to show options. I want to send the file directly from app1 to app2 if app2 is installed.

At first I tried using custom URL schemes by modifiying [this example](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-sdk-working-with-url-schemes--mobile-6629). It is good for sending some strings but I couldn't find I way to send files with custom URLs. I've tried to encode file to `base64` string and appending to URL. It didn't work. URL becomes broken.

Then I searched for implementing [UIDocumentInteractionController Uti](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uidocumentinteractioncontroller/1616802-uti) as `Instagram` and `WhatsApp` does. But I couldn't find any sufficient examples. This is the right way I guess but there isn't much information to go on.

How could I achieve this with the methods mentioned above? (App groups, keychain, pasteboard are not good options for me)

Comment: you want some magic.

Comment: @IlyaByshevski if whatsapp, instagram and other apps can do it it's not magic I guess :)

Comment: 1. bring a good example of what do they doing!
how did instagram sending file directly to another app?

2. both of applications are yours? that are taking part in process

Comment: @IlyaByshevski 1. instagram not sending it, instagram is the receiver, other apps can send photos to instagram. You can see what it can do in the instagram hooks link I gave in question. 2. both apps are mine.

Comment: other apps can send photos to instagram via share extension.

Answer (score 0):

This is very old question, but I think, you tried to find something like this:

If you would like other applications to open your app based on a file type, you can register your document request in the application plist file. This provides a means to associate any file type with your iOS app.

Include the **CFBundleDocumentTypes** key, which is an array of dictionaries, where each entry defines information about the file type(s) your app supports.

Here are some useful links:

[iOS Tips and Tricks: Associate a File Type with your App](https://www.infragistics.com/community/blogs/b/stevez/posts/ios-tips-and-tricks-associate-a-file-type-with-your-app-part-3)

[How to register file types supported by an iOS app](http://iosdevelopertips.com/core-services/how-to-register-file-types-supported-by-an-ios-app.html)

[How To Import and Export App Data Via Email in your iOS App](https://www.raywenderlich.com/3109-email-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-import-and-export-app-data-via-email-in-your-ios-app)